How to read messages in MessagePack format from Kafka and insert them to Clickhouse
I have Kafka topic with values in MessagePack format. I'm trying to read messages from it and insert them to Clickhouse table, each message in separate line, the columns match the keys in the message.
I'm creating table with Kafka engine:
CREATE TABLE db.queue
(
    msg String
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:8000',
 kafka_topic_list = 'topic-name',
 kafka_group_name = 'queue_reader_123',
 kafka_format = 'MsgPack'

and destination table:
CREATE TABLE db.content (
    ts DateTime,
    topic String,
    msgKey String,
    part UInt64,
    offset UInt64,
    msg String
)ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY msg

and materialized view:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW db.queue_to_content TO db.content (
    ts DateTime,
    topic String,
    msgKey String,
    part UInt64,
    offset UInt64,
    msg String
) AS SELECT
    _timestamp AS ts,
    _topic AS topic,
    _key AS msgKey,
    _partition AS part,
    _offset AS offset,
    msg
FROM db.queue

But I get an error:
2024.07.15 11:44:13.936899 [ 2018 ] {} <Error> StorageKafka (queue): void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t) Code: 44. DB::Exception: Cannot insert MessagePack map into column with type String.: while parsing Kafka message (topic: topic-name, partition: 0, offset: 0)': While executing Kafka. (ILLEGAL_COLUMN), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

I can read messages as raw encoded string if I specify kafka_format='LineAsString in the first table, but I didn't find any function like JSONExtractString to extract specific field by name.


msg String


MessagePack map into column with type String

The error message indicates that your msg has a type Map not String.
Try msg Map(String, String) or something.

I've already tried it, but now I get another error:
2024.07.16 06:59:05.158628 [ 2020 ] {}  StorageKafka (queue): void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t) Code: 44. DB::Exception: Cannot insert MessagePack integer into column with type String.: while parsing Kafka message (topic: topic-name, partition: 0, offset: 0)': While executing Kafka. (ILLEGAL_COLUMN), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below): It's due to that there are different types of columns in message value

But do you know what is in your message? Try Map(Int64, String)

Message has keys of type String and values of type Int, Float, String and Bool, so Map with fixed types doesn't work

@Maria maybe you can try out the experimental Variant type. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/variant, so try to use Map(String, Variant(Int64, Float64, String).
